# Not able to call application delegate method

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I am developing app with finding audio frequency by using FFT. In my app, I am not able to call application delegate method in app delegate class as given in below, but I could able to call other custom methods in app delegate class. What mistake I have done? 
Please help me!

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: why are you trying to call this method? it is called automatically after the application has completed the start up sequence.

Comment: @falconcreek It is not called automatically and also I am not trying to to call any other place. I dont know why this method not called automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your project files have got a bit mixed up. To be honest, it's probably easier to start with a new application template as a base and then add your changes into it. If that is not possible, have a look at the following

In your {project_name}.plist file under the Resources folder you should see a setting

```
Main nib file base name
```

This will tell you which nib file is loaded at the start (normally MainWindow). Open this file and have a look for 'Files Owner' 'UIApplication'. Right click on this and there should be a link to the delegate. If it isn't there, then that's your problem

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your application delegate inherits from `NSObject` and **NOT** `NSApplication` as `NSApplication` is a singleton. Otherwise your application object will be its own delegate.

Comment: ya sure, I am inherits from NSObject only

Answer (score 0):

You should now be using `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`